# Prove a quotient map is closed under an equivalence relation

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to proove the following.

Let A be a closed subspace of a topological space X. Define an equivalence
relation on $X$ by $x ∼ y$ if $x = y$ or both $x$ and $y$ are in A. Let $X^*$ be the quotient space
of $X$ under this equivalence relation.

Prove that the quotient map $p : X → X^∗$
is a closed map.

So my point of departure, is to show that a closed set in $X$ is also closed in $X^* $.
From the definition of a closed map, if $A$ is in $X$ then $f(A)$ is in $X^*$.

But I don't get what role the equivalence relation plays in this context?

Comment: Your question is somewhat unclear. Your own post describes the role of the equivalence relation: *Let $X^*$ be the quotient space of $X$ under this equivalence relation*. Are you asking what that means?

Comment: Apologies for the unclear question! Yes, I would like to know what that means.

Comment: So, for example, [these basic concepts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_(topology)) are unfamiliar to you?

Comment: No, they are not. But I want to understand how to implement them in the proof.

Comment: Points of $X*$ are equivalence classes $[x]$. You have to show that if $A$ is closed, so is $A* = \{[x] : x \in A\}$.

Comment: The title of your question does not make sense. A map camnot be closed under an  equivalence relation. What you mean is "Prove a quotient map which is determined by an equivalence relation is a closed map."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quotient maps are in general not closed maps. Let us show that in your example $p$ is a closed map.

The space $X^*$ has the quotient topology which means that $B \subset X^*$ is closed in $X^*$ iff $p^{-1}(B)$ is closed in $X$.

Now let $C \subset X$ be closed. We have to show that $p(C)$ is closed in $X^*$. This is equivalent to showing that $p^{-1}(p(C))$ is closed in $X$.

Case 1. $C \cap A = \emptyset$. Then $p^{-1}(p(C)) = C$ which is closed.

Case 2. $C \cap A \ne \emptyset$. Then $p^{-1}(p(C)) = C \cup A$ which is closed.

Note that it is essential that $A$ is closed in $X$. For a non-closed $A$ the map $p$ is in general not closed.